# cleaning text file after parsing a PDF

Tags: python, parsing, pdf, python-3.x, text

I have parsed a PDF and cleaned it to the best of my ability but I am stuck at aligning the information in the text file.

my output looks like this:

```
Zone
1
Report Name
ARREST
Incident Time
01:41
Location of Occurrence
1300 block Liverpool St
Neighborhood
Highland Park
Incident
14081898
Age
27
Gender
M
Section
3921(a)
3925
903
Description
Theft by Unlawful Taking or Disposition - Movable item
Receiving Stolen Property.
Criminal Conspiracy.
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Zone:    1
Report Name:    ARREST
Incident Time:    01:41
Location of Occurrence:    1300 block Liverpool St
Neighborhood:    Highland Park
Incident:    14081898
Age:    27
Gender:    M
Section, Description:
3921(a): Theft by Unlawful Taking or Disposition - Movable item
3925: Receiving Stolen Property.
903: Criminal Conspiracy.
```

I have tried to enumerate over the list but the issue is that some of the fields are not there.  So this makes it pull the wrong information.

Here is the code to parse the PDF

```
import os
import urllib2
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

def parsePDF(infile, outfile):

    password = ''
    pagenos = set()
    maxpages = 0
    # output option
    outtype = 'text'
    imagewriter = None
    rotation = 0
    stripcontrol = False
    layoutmode = 'normal'
    codec = 'utf-8'
    pageno = 1
    scale = 1
    caching = True
    showpageno = True
    laparams = LAParams()
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager(caching=caching)

    if outfile:
        outfp = file(outfile, 'w+')
    else:
        outfp = sys.stdout

    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, outfp, codec=codec, laparams=laparams, imagewriter=imagewriter)
    fp = file(infile, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos,
                                      maxpages=maxpages, password=password,
                                      caching=caching, check_extractable=True):

        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    outfp.close()
    return  


# Set time zone to EST
#os.environ['TZ'] = 'America/New_York'
#time.tzset()

# make sure folder system is set up
if not os.path.exists("../pdf/"):
    os.makedirs("../pdf/")
if not os.path.exists("../txt/"):
    os.makedirs("../txt/")

# Get yesterday's name and lowercase it
yesterday = (datetime.today() - timedelta(1))
yesterday_string = yesterday.strftime("%A").lower()

# Also make a numberical representation of date for filename purposes
yesterday_short = yesterday.strftime("%Y%m%d")

# Get pdf from blotter site, save it in a file
pdf = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.city.pittsburgh.pa.us/police/blotter/blotter_" + yesterday_string + ".pdf").read();
f = file("../pdf/" + yesterday_short + ".pdf", "w+")
f.write(pdf)
f.close()

# Convert pdf to text file
parsePDF("../pdf/" + yesterday_short + ".pdf", "../txt/" + yesterday_short + ".txt")

# Save text file contents in variable
parsed_pdf = file("../txt/" + yesterday_short + ".txt", "r").read()
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
import os

OddsnEnds = [ "PITTSBURGH BUREAU OF POLICE", "Incident Blotter", "Sorted by:", "DISCLAIMER:", "Incident Date", "assumes", "Page", "Report Name"]    


if not os.path.exists("../out/"):
    os.makedirs("../out/")  
with open("../txt/20140731.txt", 'r') as file:
    blotterList = file.readlines()

with open("../out/test2.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    cleanList = []
    for line in blotterList:
        if not any ([o in line for o in OddsnEnds]):
            cleanList.append(line)
    while '\n' in cleanList:
        cleanList.remove('\n')
    for i in [i for i, j in enumerate(cleanList) if j == 'ARREST\n']:
        print ('Incident:%s' % cleanList[i])
    for i in [i for i, j in enumerate(cleanList) if j == 'Incident Time\n']:
            print ('Time:%s' % cleanList[i+1])
```

But the enumerate gets me an output of

```
Time:16:20

Time:17:40

Time:17:53

Time:18:05

Time:Location of Occurrence
```

because time was not given for that incident.  also side note is all strings end with \n.

Any and all ideas and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted but I also can't quite understand your problem.. Is the Time printing is the problem? Or is it that you want your pdf output to be as the second paragraph?

Comment: my current output is the top example.  I am trying to go through the list of strings and change the output to what the 2nd example is.  I have tried to use enumerate to go through the list and change structure of the list and then output it to a text file but it breaks when fields are blank

Comment: Can you please add the code that generates the top example? I believe it is better off changing it there

Comment: I adjusted the question to include the parse code

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way of scraping PDF files for text it to use `pdftotext` (from the [poppler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_%28software%29) utilities) with the `-layout` option. It is excellent at retaining the original layout of the document.

You can use this from Python using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: This worked really well. Watermarks disappeared from my pdf, figure as well. It still has some minor problems with equations. But otherwise very good.

Answer (score 1):

In general, text extraction from a PDF file (particularly when you want to include the formatting / spacing / layout of the text), is considered to be a task that may not always work 100% accurately. I got to know this from a support tech person at a company that produces a popular library (xpdf) for extracting text from PDFs, some time ago when I was working on a project in that area. At that time, I had explored several libraries for extracting PDF from text, including xpdf and some others. There are clear technical reasons for why they cannot always give perfect results (though they do in many cases); those reasons are to do with the nature of the PDF format and how PDF is generated. When you extract the text from some PDFs, the layout and spacing may not be preserved, even if you use an option to the library like keep_format=True or the equivalent.

The only permanent solution for this issue is to not need to extract text from PDF files. Rather, always try to use the data format and data source from which the PDF file was generated, and do your text extraction / manipulation using that. Of course that is easier said than done, if you don't have access to those sources.

Comment: Poppler, mentioned by Roland Smith in a sibling answer, is a fork of xpdf, which I mentioned in my answer, according to the Wikipedia article linked to by Roland:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_%28software%29

Comment: Understanding the issues that is why I was trying to develop an algorithm to modify the output into something I can then use.  The modification of the parser is a moot point